# How to manage emotions (low mood) while accepting the suboptimal design?

Tags: personal-problems, personal-questions

I am developer and I am the first one who sees that the some design decisions (in which I participate and which I implement later) can be bad from the technical point of view, i.e. they increase the complexity of the source code, they increase the number of special cases that should be considered and communicated to the clients, they decrease the maintainability of the code base, they kind of smell a little bit.

From the one hand I perfectly understand and accept those decisions - they are rational, they cut the right balance between budget, time and features provided to the client. From the other side they create bad emotions and low mood to me and it is really hard. Maybe I am perfectionist, maybe software developers are educated to be perfectionists (you know - all those design patterns, anti-smelling, clean code, the community efforts to create ever new, ever best and ever crystal clear frameworks, peer pressure), but sometimes you shold accept some balance and some suboptimality.

So - how to manage such emotions and low mood in such cases?

Comment: You've answered your own question, really. Budgets and deadlines do not care for perfectionism, otherwise the product would never be finished. You can raise your opinions with managers/stakeholders, but in the end, you may not be in a decision-making position, so you just have to make do.

Comment: So, you are saying that there are no mood management options, just ignore emotions?

Comment: Not ignore emotions, but try to rationalize your situation so you're not worrying about something out of your control in the first place. When a coding task is assigned to me, and the outcome will be a functional but potentially problematic solution, I can't let it bother me. I can spend months and months trying to get the perfect solution, but who would that benefit in the meantime? Not the problem, that's for sure. It would be a waste of my emotional well-being to worry so much.

Comment: If there's enough time on your hands and your superiors agree, you could still rewrite, refactor & restructure functional parts (not the design itself though) in the codebase to establish better practice later on into to the software-llifecycle..

Comment: Think of it this way: in sports they say "the most important ability is availability".  If you think you know the "perfect design" but that design won't be available in the necessary time, then it isn't perfect.  Meeting time requirements is part of a design being correct.

Comment: There's a saying in engineering (which software development is). You can build it cheap, you can build it fast, and you can build it well. In the best case, you pick 2. Perfection does not exist. Every design decision entails trade-offs.

Answer (score 7):

There's a saying that applies here "never let perfect be the enemy of good" - if you're chasing "perfection" and as a result don't even manage something that was "good", that's a problem.

One way to deal with this that you need to re-frame how you think about "perfection".

A project that can't be completed with the available budget or time **can't** be "perfect". It's got a huge flaw - it's incomplete.

A project that can't deliver the feature set for the client **can't** be "perfect". It hasn't met the requirements.

In the real world the goal is *never* to be perfect - it's to be as close to it as you can manage within the constraints you have. And there's **always** constraints, whether it's budget, time or even the capability of technology.

So don't beat yourself up over how far from perfect the outcome of a project was, congratulate yourself on how close you got - and challenge yourself to see if you can get that little bit closer next time. The bad news is that you'll never get to "perfect", but the good news is that you'll never get to "perfect" - so you can always play the game again!

Answer (score 5):

I'll turn my comments into an answer, where I can expand further.

Budgets and deadlines do not care for perfectionism, otherwise the product would never be finished. You can raise your opinions with managers/stakeholders, but in the end, you may not be in a decision-making position. It can obviously be frustrating to be in this position, but you can try to make your case with your manager or the internal stakeholders for the product. There's a fine line to be drawn between making the product perfect, and releasing that product for use.

You don't have to ignore your emotions here, but "mood management" isn't the answer. I can understand that it might be upsetting to release a buggy version, knowing fully well that if you had more time, you could fix it. Try to rationalize your situation so you're not worrying about something out of your control in the first place.

When a coding task is assigned to me, and the outcome **will** be a functional but potentially problematic solution, I can't let it bother me. I can spend months and months trying to get the perfect solution, but who would that benefit in the meantime? Not the original problem, that's for sure, and it probably wouldn't benefit you either. Stressing about the perfection of the product would tax you emotionally, likely as much as "code that smells a bit". It would be a waste of my emotional well-being to worry so much about it.

Answer (score 4):

Find something outside of work that you can give the same attention-to-detail to, without the haphazard stupid stuff that gets bundled in with the requirements for projects at work.  Take up a hobby, contribute to open-source, or go save the whales.  Whatever you do, have some sort of accomplishment to look forward to *outside* of work.  Otherwise, you'll be popping happy pills from the psychiatrist in no time flat.  Accept that work will never be a perfect situation, and know that your managers appreciate your work ethic but never to the extent that it threatens deadlines and commitments.

Answer (score -2):

Making a one-time investment to solve problems to a high standard is not the agenda of most capitalist businesses today.

Many business problems amenable to computerisation were already solved to a high standard in the 70s and 80s, but wrecking changes to the economy (which has in many cases replaced machines with cheap and unpensioned labour), and a failure to reproduce knowledge of systems and concepts built decades ago, means that the main agenda nowadays is to constantly re-invent a very shoddy wheel.

This reinvention is usually for some two-bit "entrepreneur" whose only real competitive advantage is that his employees are cheaper, and systems more shoddy, than the existing firms serving the marketplace.

Comment: How should the OP manage their "emotions and low mood " given what you say?

Comment: @MattFreake, well it may help the OP to know that what they're feeling is normal and to be expected in the circumstances where they are producing something very shoddy, and that such shoddiness has a systematic explanation. The mechanic would feel the same if he was being told to hammer the bolts straight in, rather than tighten them with a wrench. The OP seems to be somewhat depressed thinking themselves a "perfectionist", rather than simply recognising that their capabilities are so much greater than is being usefully employed.

Comment: I think you should incorporate that conclusion into the answer, at the moment I think it's easy to miss how it address the OPs question.

Comment: IMO the "get it done now, make it right another day" phenomenon, that is bothering OP, happens with both well meaning groups and not. Also happens both with groups cutting corners, and ones that are lavishly funded. IMO it's just a common response to falling behind schedule.